# R: Logical from 2 vectors on pattern match

Tags: r, pattern-matching

Trying to clean up some dirty data (for work), my data frame has a column for customer information (for our example lets say store and product) in a long weird string,  as well as a column for store and a column for product.  I can parse the store and the product from the string.  Here is where I arrive at my problem.

let's say (consider these vectors part of a larger dataframe, appended with data$ if that helps, I was just working with them as vectors thinking it may speed up the code not having to pull the whole dataframe):

```
WeirdString <- c("fname: john; lname:smith; store:Amazon Inc.; product:Echo", "fname: cindy; lname:smith; store:BestBuy; product:Ps-4","fname: jon; lname:smith; store:WALMART; product:Pants")
```

so I parse this to be:

```
WS_Store <- c("Amazon Inc.", "BestBuy", "WALMART")
WS_Prod <- c("Echo", "Ps-4", "Pants")
```

What's in the tables (i.e. the non-parsed columns) is:

```
DB_Store <- c("Amazon", "BEST BUY", "Other")
DB_Prod <- c("ECHO", "PS4", "Jeans")
```

I currently am using a for loop to loop through i to grepl the "true" string from the parsed string.  This takes forever, and I know R was designed to use vectorized code, So my question is, how do I eliminate the loop and use something like lapply (which I tried, and failed at, because I'm not savvy enough with lapply), or some other vectorized thing?

My current code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){     # could be i in length(DB_prod) or whatever, all vectors are the same length)
  Diff_Store[i] <- !grepl(DB_Store[i], WS_Store[i], ignore.case=T)
  Diff_Prod[i]  <- !grepl(DB_Prod[i] , WS_Prod[i] , ignore.case=T)
}
```

I intend to append those columns back into the dataframe, as the true goal is to diagnose why the database has this problem.

If there's a better way than this, rather than trying to vectorize it, I'm open to it.  The data in the DB_Store is restricted to a specific number of "stores" (in the table it comes from) but in the string, it seems to be open, which is why I use the DB as the pattern, not the x.  Product is similar, but not as restricted, this is why some have dashes and some don't.  I would love to match "close things" like Ps-4 vs. PS4, but I will probably just build a table of matches once I see how weird the string gets.  To be true though, the string may not match, which is represented by the Pants/Jeans thing.  The dataset is 2.5 million records, and there are many different "stores" and "products", and I do want to make sure they match on the same line, not "is it in the database" (which is what previous questions seem to ask, can I see if a string is in a list of strings, rather than a 1:1 comparison, and the last question did end in a loop, which takes minutes and hours to run)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this works for you:

```
check <- function(vec_a, vec_b){
   mat <- cbind(vec_a, vec_b)
   diff <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) !grepl(pattern = x[1], x = x[2], ignore.case = TRUE))
diff
}
```

Use your different vectors for stores (or products) in the arguments `vec_a` and `vec_b`, respectively (example: `diff_stores <- check(DB_Store, WS_Store)` ). This function will return a logical vector with `TRUE` values referring to items that weren't a match in the two original vectors. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: It's working!  This was perfect!  You are a savior.  What took hours now takes less than 2 minutes.